# Can we convert xcode project (xcodeproj) to swift playground (.playground) format?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I develop an ios app in xcode, I want to run this app in swift playground.
so i want to convert my .xcodeproj project in .playground format. so any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really convert your `.xcodeproj` file to a .playground file but you can add a .playground file to your `.xcodeproj` file and use it from there

Open up your `.xcodeproj` file and follow the steps below to add a `.playground` file to your project.

1. Go to `File > Save as Workspace` Save the Workspace file in the same directory as the `.xcodeproj` file
2. Create a new `.playground` file under `Source`
3. Go to `File > New > Target`. Next go to `iOS > Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework`
4. Add any files that you want to access from the `.playground` to the target membership of the Framework we created earlier.
5. Select your framework and iOS device from the build sources and Build the project
6. Import your framework to the `.playground` file

That's All :)