# Export a project to the Playgrounds app on the iPad

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ipad-playgrounds

Can I transfer the project on the Xcode application in SwiftUI language on the Mac to the iPad in the Playgrounds application

I've searched a lot about it and couldn't find anything
Can you help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Create a Swift Playgrounds App project in Xcode if you want to use the project in the Swift Playgrounds app on iPad or Mac. The other project types won't work on the Swift Playgrounds app.

Comment: For those new to all this, note that as of Xcode 14 (and likely Xcode 13), creating a Swift Playgrounds App (File > New > Project > Swift Playgrounds App) is distinct from creating a new Playground (File > New > Playground...).

Answer (score 0):

Swift Playgrounds (For iPad) isn't Xcode. It has its limitations. Here is a good question here on SO that might help: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033585/can-we-convert-xcode-project-xcodeproj-to-swift-playground-playground-forma)

I would strongly advise against using Swift Playground unless it's for an app, that does not use any package dependencies, so like a basic app.

But it's great for learning Swift!